# UITextView scroll gets stuck while using Text Kit 2

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview

I am using text kit 2 in UITextView by making **usingTextLayoutManager** property true. I am trying to add left and right indents in NSAttributedString to get indented text. When I have a long text and when I apply indents on paragraph style (NSParagraphStyle), My UITextView gets stuck and I can't scroll to bottom. I think it has something to do with contentSize of the UITextView. I have tried everything. It works fine with text kit 1, but I have to use text kit 2 for its new features.
Here's my code:

UITextView

```
import UIKit

class MyTextView: UITextView {
    
    convenience init(usingTextLayoutManager: Bool) {
        self.init(frame: .zero, textContainer: nil)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        
        setUpTextView()
        setUpAttributes()
        setUpInputAccessoryView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setUpTextView() {
        alwaysBounceVertical = true
        keyboardDismissMode = .interactiveWithAccessory
        backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    func setUpAttributes() {
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = font.pointSize * 0.15
        
        typingAttributes = [
            .font: font,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
        ]
        
        let string = "When you try your best, but you don't succeed\nWhen you get what you want, but not what you need\nWhen you feel so tired, but you can't sleep\nStuck in reverse\nAnd the tears come streaming down your face\nWhen you lose something you can't replace\nWhen you love someone, but it goes to waste\nCould it be worse?\nLights will guide you home\nAnd ignite your bones\nAnd I will try to fix you\nAnd high up above, or down below\nWhen you're too in love to let it go\nBut if you never try, you'll never know\nJust what you're worth\nLights will guide you home\nAnd ignite your bones\nAnd I will try to fix you\nTears stream down your face\nWhen you lose something you cannot replace\nTears stream down your face, and I\nTears stream down your face\nI promise you I will learn from my mistakes\nTears stream down your face, and I\nLights will guide you home\nAnd ignite your bones\nAnd I will try to fix you\nWhen you try your best, but you don't succeed\nWhen you get what you want, but not what you need\nWhen you feel so tired, but you can't sleep\nStuck in reverse\nAnd the tears come streaming down your face\nWhen you lose something you can't replace\nWhen you love someone, but it goes to waste\nCould it be worse?\nLights will guide you home\nAnd ignite your bones\nAnd I will try to fix you\nAnd high up above, or down below\nWhen you're too in love to let it go\nBut if you never try, you'll never know\nJust what you're worth\nLights will guide you home\nAnd ignite your bones\nAnd I will try to fix you\nTears stream down your face\nWhen you lose something you cannot replace\nTears stream down your face, and I\nTears stream down your face\nI promise you I will learn from my mistakes\nTears stream down your face, and I\nLights will guide you home\nAnd ignite your bones\nAnd I will try to fix you"
        
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: string,
            attributes: [
                .font: font,
                .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]
        )
        
        textStorage.setAttributedString(attributedString)
    }
    
    func indentLeft() {
        let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
        let paragraphRange = mutableAttributedText.mutableString.paragraphRange(for: selectedRange)
        
        textStorage.enumerateAttribute(.paragraphStyle, in: paragraphRange) { attribute, range, _ in
            if let paragraphStyle = attribute as? NSParagraphStyle {
                let newParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
                if newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent > 0 {
                    newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent -= 40
                    newParagraphStyle.headIndent -= 40
                } else {
                    newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
                    newParagraphStyle.headIndent = 0
                }
                textStorage.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: newParagraphStyle, range: range)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func indentRight() {
        let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
        let paragraphRange = mutableAttributedText.mutableString.paragraphRange(for: selectedRange)
        
        textStorage.enumerateAttribute(.paragraphStyle, in: paragraphRange) { attribute, range, _ in
            if let paragraphStyle = attribute as? NSParagraphStyle {
                let newParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
                if newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent < 160 {
                    newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent += 40
                    newParagraphStyle.headIndent += 40
                } else {
                    newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
                    newParagraphStyle.headIndent = 0
                }
                textStorage.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: newParagraphStyle, range: range)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func setUpInputAccessoryView() {
        let view = AccessoryView(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: .zero, height: 50)))
        view.textView = self
        inputAccessoryView = view
    }
}
```

ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var textView: MyTextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setUpTextView()
    }
    
    func setUpTextView() {
        textView = MyTextView()
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.addSubview(textView)
        setUpConstraints()
        let _ = textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    
    func setUpConstraints() {
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        [   textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ].forEach {
            $0.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Accessory view for textView

```
class AccessoryView: UIView {
    
    weak var textView: MyTextView?
    
    let indentLeft: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "lessthan"), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    let indentRight: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "greaterthan"), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        backgroundColor = .white
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        
        addSubview(indentLeft)
        indentLeft.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        indentLeft.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        indentLeft.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        indentLeft.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        indentLeft.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
        indentLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleIndentLeft), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        addSubview(indentRight)
        indentRight.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        indentRight.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        indentRight.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: indentLeft.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        indentRight.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        indentRight.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
        indentRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleIndentRight), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func handleIndentLeft(button: UIButton) {
        guard let textView = textView else {
            return
        }
        
        textView.indentLeft()
    }
    
    @objc func handleIndentRight(button: UIButton) {
        guard let textView = textView else {
            return
        }
        
        textView.indentRight()
    }
}
```

How recreate issue:

1. Run it in your phone.
2. Select all text.
3. press right indent button 2-3 times
4. then scroll to top and again scroll to bottom.

Do you know why is it happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I've played with your project a bit, trying different solutions. Note that, after the indentation, the scrolling "bounces" back when trying to scroll to bottom, however if you keep doing it with two fingers alternatively you can reach the bottom, and after that you can scroll normally. It's a behaviour that I've found quite in a few apps, and I'm not really sure why it happens.

However I've found a solution: you can reset `isScrollEnabled` and then you can scroll freely again. This fixed the issue, at least on my device (iPhone 13 Pro, iOS 16.5.1).

```
func indentRight() {
    let mutableAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
    let paragraphRange = mutableAttributedText.mutableString.paragraphRange(for: selectedRange)
    
    textStorage.enumerateAttribute(.paragraphStyle, in: paragraphRange) { attribute, range, _ in
        if let paragraphStyle = attribute as? NSParagraphStyle {
            let newParagraphStyle = paragraphStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
            if newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent < 160 {
                newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent += 40
                newParagraphStyle.headIndent += 40
            } else {
                newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
                newParagraphStyle.headIndent = 0
            }
            textStorage.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: newParagraphStyle, range: range)

        }
    }

    self.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.isScrollEnabled = true
    self.sizeToFit()
}
```

**EDIT:** I was testing only by doing 3 indentations, apparently the issue pointed out in the comment happens only for the 2nd and 4th indentation, at least on my device. Well, I added `self.sizeToFit()`, I also moved the whole reset lines out of the loop. This solves the issue definitely.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It solves the original issue but causes a new issue. When you scroll to the top you see a very large blank space, it's like extra contentSize, and then text jumps to top. I am testing on iPhone 12 mini, iOS 16.5.1

Comment: @FE_Tech you're right, my bad, I was testing only by doing three indentations, where this doesn't happen. I've edited my answer, check it out, it should solve the whole issue now.

Comment: it's still happening at 3rd indentation level. See this https://drive.google.com/file/d/17yBP1hnEjbrZHPggNhoTKSuTxAaSAMsg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I can't no longer reproduce you issue. It works on my device.